# Netcat, Syslog, UDP, and <134>

Tags: syslog, udp, netcat

Listening with netcat on UDP 514 to syslog data I see that each sent log message is separated by `<134>`.

Does anyone note what `<134`> is?

Comment: Ah okay it is defined in http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424#section-6.2 -- trying to parse that :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is part of the header. "The Priority value is calculated by first multiplying the Facility number by 8 and then adding the numerical value of the Severity." So 134 / 8 = 16 (facility local0) remainder 6 (severity Informational: informational messages).

```
SYSLOG-MSG      = HEADER SP STRUCTURED-DATA [SP MSG]
HEADER          = PRI...
PRI             = "<" PRIVAL ">"
PRIVAL          = 1*3DIGIT ; range 0 .. 191
```

Answer (score -3):

0134 is the octal code for backslash `\`.

This is an escape char, to avoid possible sql injections on syslog SQL backends.

See [this message](https://lists.balabit.hu/pipermail/syslog-ng/2009-June/013013.html) on the syslog-ng mailing list.

Comment: Hmm...I don't think so.